# Does and how exacly OR and || operators are different?

Tags: php, operators, logical-operators

PHP's logical operator for 'or' is:

1. `||`
2. `OR`

They do the same. Don't they?

Once I've seen somewhere an explanation of actual logic of thos two different (as stated) operators.

I ask to confirm and if possible provide explanation that they ARE different.

Explenation that I've seen:

1. `||` as soon as it finds `TRUE` it returns `TRUE` and not checking
   proceding conditions
2. `OR` even if first checked value is `TRUE` it stil checks another
   right hand conditions, but we all know it doesn't matter for us, as
   it will output `TRUE` anyways.

I hope it's clear what and why I ask it.

Comment: refer to this question Logical Operators, || or OR?

Comment: They work the same, only difference is their precedence.

Comment: Explain your -1 or gtfo from my questions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, they have different precedence: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

```
$a = false || true;
$b = false or true;
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Returns:

```
$a ---> bool(true)
$b ---> bool(false)
```